# How do I resolve this Moq error? System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch

Tags: parameters, moq

I am using Moq in my nUnit test cases.

Here's what my test case looks like:

```
        IList<ChartFieldDepartment> coaDepartments = new List<ChartFieldDepartment>() {
                new ChartFieldDepartment { ChartFieldKey="1000", Description="Corporate Allocation"},
                new ChartFieldDepartment { ChartFieldKey="1010", Description="Contribution to Capital"}
        };

        Mock<IChartFieldRepository> mockChartFieldRepository = new Mock<IChartFieldRepository>();
        mockChartFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.RetrieveChartFieldDepartments(It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(coaDepartments.AsQueryable);

        ChartFieldDomainService chartFieldDomainService = new ChartFieldDomainService(mockChartFieldRepository.Object);

        // this line fails! I get System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch
        IQueryable<ChartFieldDepartment> departments = chartFieldDomainService.RetrieveChartFieldDepartments();
```

Here is my `ChartFieldDomainService`:

```
public class ChartFieldDomainService : IChartFieldDomainService
{
    private IChartFieldRepository _chartFieldRepository = null;

    public ChartFieldDomainService(IChartFieldRepository repository)
    {
        _chartFieldRepository = repository;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<ChartFieldDepartment> RetrieveChartFieldDepartments()
    {
        return _chartFieldRepository.RetrieveChartFieldDepartments(true); // always refresh, get latest
    }
    //....
 }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: SOLUTION

The following change in syntax fixed the problem.

Original Line:

```
        mockChartFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.RetrieveChartFieldDepartments(It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns(coaDepartments.AsQueryable());
```

Updated Line:

```
        mockChartFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.RetrieveChartFieldDepartments(It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Returns((bool x) => coaDepartments.AsQueryable());
```

Comment: I don't think you need the lambda; just add the parentheses.

Answer (score 11):

Change it to

```
.Returns(coaDepartments.AsQueryable());
```

(Which is not at all obvious from the error message.)

Comment: this is what is causing the problems in the first place. adding the lambda (bool x) => coaDepartments.AsQueryable() was what fixed the parameter mismatch.

Comment: @Raymond: All we have to go on is your original post. The first example shows `.Returns(coaDepartments.AsQueryable)`. In testing, I found that it would not run without the parentheses but would run with the parentheses.

Comment: @TrueWill I was looking at this error for a while now without realising i forgot the (). Adding them solved my problem.

Comment: Not adding parenthesis was causing intermittent failures in builds. Issue fixed by adding parenthesis or writing it as ()=>results.ToList(). Does anyone know why this parenthesis is required ?